# Javascript countdown clock in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, dynamic, model-view-controller, countdown, countdowntimer

I would like to display the live countdown clock for each row of my diagram. 
and @solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadLine is the due time for each row.
I can display the countdown, but only for first row(duplicate ID). Please help me. Thank you

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var solicitation in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">


                <a href="@string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBOListingLink"], (string) ViewBag.CallingIC, solicitation.SolicitationNumber)" target="_blank">
                    @solicitation.SolicitationNumber
                </a>

            </td>
            <td>
                @solicitation.GetNoticeTypeName()
            </td>
            <td>
                @solicitation.SolicitationTitle
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%;">
                @*@solicitation.eCPSUser_UserType.AppUser.AppUserFullName*@
                @solicitation.PrimaryAssociation.appUser.AppUserFullName
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 15%;">
                @solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline
            </td>
            <td>
                <span style="display: block;">@solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline</span>
                <span class="#countDownCell"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: change your id into a class? IDs shouldn't be duplicate.. Also put an example of your problem in action in a jsfiddle. Makes it easier to see what your problem is..

Answer (score -1):

```
     @{
                        var vYear = Convert.ToDateTime(solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline).Year;
                        var vMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline).Month;
                        var vDay = Convert.ToDateTime(solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline).Day;
                        var vMinute = Convert.ToDateTime(solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline).Minute;
                        var vSecond = Convert.ToDateTime(solicitation.SolicitationResponseDeadline).Second;

                    }

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var note = "the winter is coming";
                        var nYear = [@vYear];
                        var nMonth = [@vMonth];
                        var nDay = [@vDay];
                        var nMinute = [@vMinute];
                        var nSecond = [@vSecond];
                        tdy = new Date(nYear, nMonth, nDay, nMinute, nSecond);

 $("#testCountDown").countdown({
            until: tdy,
            compact: true,
            description: ""
        });
```

Comment: I can't test this. Your problem is probably the fact that you're duplicating id's but without a working example I can't know

Comment: The data is from database. when you display "#testcountdown", it only show at first row.

Comment: You shouldn't use IDs on your page more than once. That's how you get bugs. But without actually seeing a piece of static HTML and javascript to reproduce your problem I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: i can't add the image. if you don't mid i can send to you by email. and show you my problem. Thank you